# URL rewriting messes up main directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

So I have this URL

```
http://localhost/site/
```

And I also have another file which makes it look like this

```
http://localhost/site/info.php?url=website
```

And I turned that into

```
http://localhost/site/info/website.com
```

With

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
    
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
    
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ info.php?url=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ info.php?url=$1
```

And now when I go to `http://localhost/site/` I end up getting

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /info.php was not found on this server.

But I'm only trying to get to the index visit `http://localhost/site/` not `http://localhost/site/info`

Comment: site/ matches the regex ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ and so will be rewritten to info.php?url=site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you wanted to only rewrite when the url starts with 'site/info/'

I haven't tried this so it might not work...

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^site/info/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ info.php?url=$1
RewriteRule ^site/info/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ info.php?url=$1
```

Also, are you sure you want to remove the .com when you rewrite this...?
    `http://localhost/site/info/website.com`